# Why won't my C, Circular Deque program exit the print function?

Tags: c, linked-list, deque, circular-list

I am doing a Circular Linked List Deque assignment in C.  The code runs fine and the outputs are as expected, but for some reason after the circularListReverse()

```
void circularListReverse(struct CircularList* list)
{
     assert(!circularListIsEmpty(list));

     struct Link *curLink;
     struct Link *tempLink;

     curLink = list->sentinel;

     do {
         tempLink = curLink->next;
         curLink->next = curLink->prev;
         curLink->prev = tempLink;
         curLink = tempLink;
     } while (curLink != list->sentinel);
}
```

is called on the list, the circularListPrint()

```
void circularListPrint(struct CircularList* list)
 {
     assert(!circularListIsEmpty(list));
     struct Link *newLink = list->sentinel->next;
     while(newLink != list->sentinel) {
         printf("%g ", newLink->value);
         newLink = newLink->next;
     }
     printf("\n");  //This prints, so it exits the loop
 }
```

function hangs after it prints all of the expected results.  After troubleshooting for hours I have found that the program exits the while loop which does the printing, but does not exit the function.   This function DOES work properly before the reverse function is called.  Why is it hanging?

Below is the driver:

```
 #include "circularList.h"
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {  
     struct CircularList* deque = circularListCreate(); 
     circularListAddBack(deque, (TYPE)1);
     circularListAddBack(deque, (TYPE)2);
     circularListAddBack(deque, (TYPE)3);
     circularListAddFront(deque, (TYPE)4);
     circularListAddFront(deque, (TYPE)5);
     circularListAddFront(deque, (TYPE)6);
     circularListPrint(deque);                //Works fine
     printf("%g\n", circularListFront(deque));
     printf("%g\n", circularListBack(deque));

     circularListRemoveFront(deque);
     circularListRemoveBack(deque);
     circularListPrint(deque);

     circularListReverse(deque);
     circularListPrint(deque);  //HANGS

     //Debug
     printf("\nEnd of print\n"); //This does NOT print, so function never exits

     circularListDestroy(deque);

    return 0;
 }
```

List and Link structures:

```
 struct Link
 {
     TYPE value;
     struct Link * next;
     struct Link * prev;
 };

 struct CircularList
 {
     int size;
     struct Link* sentinel;
 };
```

Add functions:

```
 static void addLinkAfter(struct CircularList* list, struct Link* link, TYPE value)
 {
     assert(link != NULL);
     struct Link *newLink = createLink(value);
     newLink->prev = link;
     newLink->next = link->next;

     newLink->next->prev = newLink;
     link->next = newLink;

     list->size++;
 }

 /**
  * Adds a new link with the given value to the front of the deque.
  */
 void circularListAddFront(struct CircularList* list, TYPE value)
 {
     assert(list != NULL);
     addLinkAfter(list, list->sentinel, value);
 }

 /**
  * Adds a new link with the given value to the back of the deque.
  */
 void circularListAddBack(struct CircularList* list, TYPE value)
 {
     assert(list != NULL);
     addLinkAfter(list, list->sentinel->prev, value);
 }
```

Create Circular List:

```
 /**
  * Allocates and initializes a list.
  */
 struct CircularList* circularListCreate()
 {
     struct CircularList* list = malloc(sizeof(struct CircularList));
     init(list);
     return list;
 }

 /**
  * Allocates the list's sentinel and sets the size to 0.
  * The sentinel's next and prev should point to the sentinel itself.
  */
 static void init(struct CircularList* list)
 {
     assert(list != 0);

     list->sentinel = (struct Link *)malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
     assert(list->sentinel != 0);

     list->sentinel->next = list->sentinel;
     list->sentinel->prev = list->sentinel;
     list->size = 0;
     list->sentinel->value = 0;
 }
```

Removes:

```
 static void removeLink(struct CircularList* list, struct Link* link)
 {
     // FIXME: you must write this
     assert(!circularListIsEmpty(list));
     assert(link != NULL);
     link->prev->next = link->next;
     link->next->prev = link->prev;
     free(link);
     list->size--;
 }

 /**
  * Removes the link at the front of the deque.
  */
 void circularListRemoveFront(struct CircularList* list)
 {
     assert(!circularListIsEmpty(list));
     removeLink(list, list->sentinel->next);

 }

 /**
  * Removes the link at the back of the deque.
  */
 void circularListRemoveBack(struct CircularList* list)
 {
     assert(!circularListIsEmpty(list));
     removeLink(list, list->sentinel->prev);
 }
```

The output is

```
 6 5 4 1 2 3
 6
 3
 5 4 1 2
 2 1 4 5
 //Cursor sits here and program doesn't exit
```

Comment: Please use debugger.

Comment: I am using valgrind and it is showing me nothing.  I am debugging using print statements.

Comment: Not valgrind, valgrind is not a debugger. Use **gdb**, and step through the code line by line. You will quickly figure out the problem.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to use the debugger in netbeans.  I have my program building to an external host (School's server).  ANy suggestions?

Comment: Please add declaration of circularListAddFront... and the rest of functions you use in this example. Make sure it compiles. Otherwise we cannot help you...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: circularListAddFront and circularListAddBack definitions are missing

Comment: I added them in the edit.

Comment: Thank you. Let me have a look.

Comment: What's in `circularListCreate()`?

Comment: Added circularListCreate() in the edit.

Comment: And `init()`?  All your node adding functions depend on at least one node being in the list already... and what's in that initial node may be the source of the problem.

Comment: Added to the edit.

Comment: Asymptotically, we're getting ever closer to that complete example.

Comment: @antman1p: Please read about how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- as your question is now, it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: I understand how.  I keep getting asked to add more of my functions.  This is why it is getting less than minimal. Your comment helps nothing.

Comment: Please paste the code circularListRemoveFront and circularListRemoveBack as I suspect they are the culprit - I pasted a code that works, but it doesn't include these two functions.

Comment: If I fill in my own versions of the functions you haven't shown yet, it works fine for me... so look into those.

Comment: Pasted.  Apparently some people are bound and determined to ruin this site.  It is on hold for not being minimal when I am being asked to add the functions.

Comment: Again, it's not on hold because it's not minimal. No-one has said that. It's on hold because it isn't (wasn't) Complete and Verifiable.

Comment: It should be verifiable once it is complete.  I am trying to keep it as minimal as possible as to not give out my whole code to the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce. This code works fine (fixing memory leaks left as the reader's exercise). This code doesn't execute `circularListRemoveFront` and `circularListRemoveBack` (because you didn't paste their code), therefore it is likely one or both of them may be the culprit.

My code differs with `circularListCreate` implementation (there was no code of it pasted initially) but this is unlikely to be the issue.

---

EDIT:

Added `circularListRemoveBack` and `circularListRemoveFront` after you pasted their code. Code works, you must have some local issue. Please **copy**, **paste** and **compile**, try if it works.

output is:

> 6 5 4 1 2 3
>
> 5 4 1 2
>
> 2 1 4 5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TYPE double
struct Link
 {
     double value;
     struct Link * next;
     struct Link * prev;
 };

 struct CircularList
 {
     int size; 
     struct Link* sentinel;
 };
 
 void circularListReverse(struct CircularList* list)
 {
     struct Link *curLink;
     struct Link *tempLink;

     curLink = list->sentinel;

     do {
         tempLink = curLink->next;
         curLink->next = curLink->prev;
         curLink->prev = tempLink;
         curLink = tempLink;
     } while (curLink != list->sentinel);
}
void circularListPrint(struct CircularList* list)
 {
     struct Link *newLink = list->sentinel->next;
     while(newLink != list->sentinel) {
         printf("%g ", newLink->value);
         newLink = newLink->next;
     }
     printf("\n");  //This prints, so it exits the loop
 } 

struct Link* createLink(TYPE value)
{
    struct Link *l = malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
    l->value = value;
    return l;
}

static void addLinkAfter(struct CircularList* list, struct Link* link, TYPE value)
 {
     struct Link *newLink = createLink(value);
     newLink->prev = link;
     newLink->next = link->next;

     newLink->next->prev = newLink;
     link->next = newLink;

     list->size++;
 }

 /**
  * Adds a new link with the given value to the front of the deque.
  */
 void circularListAddFront(struct CircularList* list, TYPE value)
 {
     addLinkAfter(list, list->sentinel, value);
 }

 /**
  * Adds a new link with the given value to the back of the deque.
  */
 void circularListAddBack(struct CircularList* list, TYPE value)
 {
     addLinkAfter(list, list->sentinel->prev, value);
 }

static void removeLink(struct CircularList *list, struct Link *link)
{
    link->prev->next = link->next;
    link->next->prev = link->prev;
    free(link);
    list->size--;
}

 void circularListRemoveBack(struct CircularList* list)
{
    removeLink(list, list->sentinel->prev);
}

 void circularListRemoveFront(struct CircularList* list)
{
    removeLink(list, list->sentinel->next);
}

struct CircularList* create()
{
    struct CircularList *l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
    l->sentinel = malloc(sizeof(*l->sentinel));
    l->sentinel->prev = l->sentinel->next = l->sentinel;
    l->size = l->sentinel->value = 0;
}
int main(void) {
     struct CircularList* deque = create();
     circularListAddBack(deque, (TYPE)1);
     circularListAddBack(deque, (TYPE)2);
     circularListAddBack(deque, (TYPE)3);
     circularListAddFront(deque, (TYPE)4);
     circularListAddFront(deque, (TYPE)5);
     circularListAddFront(deque, (TYPE)6);
     circularListPrint(deque);                //Works fine

     circularListRemoveFront(deque);
     circularListRemoveBack(deque);
     circularListPrint(deque);
     
     circularListReverse(deque);
     circularListPrint(deque);  //HANGS

     //Debug
     printf("\nEnd of print\n"); //This does NOT print, so function never exits

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should I paste those?  My question is getting slammed now for not following guidelines.

Comment: Absolutely, please.

Comment: Well now I can't.  Apparently the question is now put on hold.  This site is getting ridiculous.

Comment: @antman1p You can still edit the question, and it can be re-opened when it's answerable. You're not getting slammed because you're adding too much, on the contrary – "Verifiable" is much more important than "Minimal" in the Minimal, Complete, Verifiable rule.

Comment: Voted to reopen. @antman1p You can still edit the question. Please insert missing code.

Comment: Thank you.  I edited.  Hopefully it reopens.

Comment: This is really weird.  I cannot figure out what the problem is for the life of me.

Comment: Did you copy/paste?

Comment: No, Is there any differences?

Comment: Yes, please copy/paste/recompile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134916/discussion-between-antman1p-and-not-sure-why-it-is-so).